# Angular JS ng-repeat doesn´t showing data correctly

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a strange problem when using ng-repeat.
Only as additional information, I am using ui-router as well.

I did a test with a simple markup that query some data in my local node server and shows with ng-repeat.

To make the test, I click  a button to add a new row to server and next, I query the server again to get the new rows updated.

The problem is that  the server return correctly all data with the new row added included, but ng-repeat is no showing the rows just added.

Here is more details of the problem.

Firstly, when the page is loaded I have

```
RowId
1
2
```

After I click the "Add and Refresh Row" button, I´d expect to have on the screen:

```
RowId
1
2
5
```

But I still have only:

```
RowId
1
2
```

In console,I checked the return data from my server after I add a row and the data returned is:

```
{id:1,name:'John Doe'},
{id:2,name:'Mary Doe'}
{id:5,name:'teste'}
```

where item id=5 is the row just added, buit it doesn´t appears with ng-repeat.

What am I doing wrong?

//markup

```
<div  ng-controller="configClinicaClinicaCtrl"> 
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-click="saveClinica()">Add and Refresh Row</a>
  <div>RowId</div>
  <div ng-repeat="row in dados track by $index">
      {{row.id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

//local server with server.js script at node.js

```
var clinicas=[
{id:1,name:'John Doe'},
{id:2,name:'Mary Doe'}
];

//get clinicas
app.get('/clinicas', function(req, res) {
  res.json(clinicas);
});

//insert clinica
app.post('/clinicas', function(req, res) {
  clinicas.push(req.body);
  res.json(true);
});
```

//controller

```
angular.module("clinang").controller('configClinicaClinicaCtrl',['$scope','$http', '$state', function($scope,$http, $state) {
      $scope.dados={};
      $scope.clinica={};
      var refreshData=function(){
        $http.get('/clinicas').then(function(response){
            $scope.dados=response.data;
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
        });
      }
      refreshData();


     $scope.saveClinica=function(){
        $scope.clinica.id=5; 
        $scope.clinica.nome='teste';
        var clinica=$scope.clinica;
        $http.post('/clinicas',{clinica}).then(function(response){
            refreshData();
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you do some form of operation outside of AngularJS, such as doing an API call you need to let AngularJS know to update itself. Try this,

```
 var refreshData=function(){
        $http.get('/clinicas').then(function(response){
            $scope.dados=response.data;
             $scope.$apply();
        }, function(error){
          console.log(error)
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just did it, but the problem continues. The RowId in ng-repeat is not updated with the new rows added

Comment: @LuizAlves should not this be an array   $scope.dados={};?

Comment: Yes, I have teamviewer. Do you want?

Comment: How can I send the id and pw to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141600/discussion-between-luiz-alves-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Than you very much, Mr Sajeetharan